# How to reason about the smoothness of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

$Edit$: I use the term "smooth" here to mean "infinitely differentiable".

I would like to ask for some advice on figuring out whether a function is smooth or not, especially when the function is a product, quotient or a composition of other functions. The two example functions which I encountered and which made me ask this are:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin (x)\exp (-\frac{1}{x^2}) & x\neq 0 \cr 0 & x = 0\end{cases}$

and

$g(x) = \begin{cases}\ln (x)\sin (2\pi x) & 0 < x \leq  1 \cr 0 & x = 0\end{cases}$

For the second one it's pretty easy to see it's not differentiable at $0$ just by applying the definition of a derivative, yet if it wasn't defined like that at point zero, I would be lost, as I am with the first one. So yeah, any advice on how to find whether these kinds of functions are smooth or not would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $\exp(-1/x^2)$ in the first one?

Comment: ah, yes, how did you know? :)

Comment: You're looking for functions that $\to 0$ at $0.$ $\exp(-1/x^2)$ is famous for $\to 0$ super fast. Note $\exp(+1/x^2)\to \infty$ super fast.

Comment: "yet if it wasn't defined like that at point zero": what do you mean by this, and how is it connected with you finding the first example challenging?

Comment: I mean that I was only able to find that the function is not smooth by figuring out that it wasn't differentiable at 0. I couldn't think of another way to approach the task. The first example, however, is differentiable at zero, so I am suddenly out of ideas for solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the first one with this theorem which is a simple consequence of the mean value theorem.

Let $f$ be defined on $(a,b)$ and differentiable except perhaps at the point $c\in(a,b).$  Suppose further that $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ exists.  Then $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f'(c)= \lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$.

Of course the given $f$ is smooth for $x\neq0$ and when we differentiate it repeatedly, we will obviously get  expressions of the form $$f^{(n)}(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)\left(\sin(x)P_n(1/x)+\cos(x)Q_n(1/x)\right)$$ for some rational functions $P_n$ and $Q_n$.

As $x\to0$, $\exp(-1/x^2)->0$ much faster than $P_n(1/x)$ and $Q_n(1/x)$ go to $\pm\infty$ so $$f(n)(0)=0,\ n=0,1,2,\dots$$